# Proving that $x\notin\mathbb{m}\implies$ $x$ is a unit, where $\mathbb{m}$ is a unique maximal ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R\ne(0)$ be a commutative unital local ring (it has a unique maximal ideal that we'll call $\mathbb{m}$). In order to show that $x\notin\mathbb{m}\implies$ $x$ is a unit I first want to prove that for a ring (not necessarily local) [$x\in$ a maximal ideal] $\iff$ [x is not a unit].

$(x)$ is the ideal generated by $x$ in $R[x]$

Here is how I did one implication:

> $x$ is a unit $\implies$ $\exists y\ :\ xy=yx=1\implies 1\in(x)$ holds $\implies$ $R\subset (x)=\{a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ so if an ideal contains $x$ it has to contain $1$ and so it cannot be maximal

with this result it is easy to prove that $x\notin\mathbb{m}\implies$ $x$ is a unit:

$x\in R\backslash\mathbb{m}$ and let's assume that there is no $y\in R$ s.t. $xy=1$. By the previous result (the implication that I didn't do) $x$ is in a maximal ideal, but $\mathbb{m}$ is the unique maximal ideal which is absurd.

Could someone point out if there is something wrong with my reasonning, and give a hint for the other implication please?

And I want to stress that although there might be a far superior proof, I would really appreciate it if I could get some feedback on what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating what is simple. After proving that $1\in(x)$, all you have to do in order to prove that $(x)\supset R$ is to note that, if $r\in R$, then $r=r\times1\in(x)$, since $(x)$ is an ideal.

The rest looks fine to me.

---

In order to prove the other implication, you can do this: let $x$ be a non-unit. Then $(x)$ is an ideal, and therefore it is contained in a maximal ideal. But here the only maximal ideal is $\mathrm m$. THerefore, $(x)\subset\mathrm m$. In other words, $x\in\mathrm m$.

Comment: Isn't that proving $m\subset (x)$ ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Ok that is true and I actually had no doubts about this particular step... But how would you do the other implication?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt I did not realize that you wanted that.It seemed to me that you only wanted someone to check whether or not what you proved is correct. I've added a proof.

Comment: Thanks for adding the proof! One last question: why does $(x)$ have to be contained in a maximal ideal?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt That's a general fact from ring theory: every ideal is contained in some maximal ideal. It's a consequence of Zorn's lemma.